# Combining nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have an object like this:

```
"data" :[{"question": "FirtName", "answer": "Daniel"},
         {"question": "LastNane", "answer": "Daniel2"},
         {"question": "Age", "answer": "80"}]
```

- I want to change it to this format using java script
  "data":

  ```
  ["FirtName" : "Daniel", "LastNane" : "Daniel2", "Age" : "80"]
  ```

Please,  assist me!

Comment: I'd love to help despite the fact that you've done nothing yourself. Perhaps the problem is that you would need to redesign the javascript language to make your desired format valid - unfortunately, in all current forms of javascript, that aint syntactically valid, at all

Comment: Please fix the errors in your question. There are spelling errors ("FirtName"? "LastNane"?) and Javascript/JSON syntax errors, a `{` is missing in the input object and the output object is even missing all `{` and `}`.

Comment: @Delali, I will suggest first fix your JSON and array. Ask a question with something you tried. What you are asking is like a book assignment

Comment: @Peter sorry for the  mistakes will do that .

Comment: @GeekAb i think the corrections should be okay  now. am new here o pardon me.

Comment: are you sure the result has `[]`, shouldn't it be `{}`

Comment: I don't really care why you need to produce an output that isn't valid javascript ... you'll have to create an object, then stringify it, then change the string to become the abomination you require

Comment: @DelaliDaniel I guess you should edit the question and make thing clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution for a input as an array of objects and an output as an object

```js
var data = [{question: "FirtName", answer: "Daniel"},
             {question: "LastNane", answer: "Daniel2"},
             {question: "Age", answer: 80}
           ];
var result = {};
data.forEach(x => {
  result[x.question] = x.answer;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: worked like magic !!! thanks Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

Keep attention to your object, thats what it should look about.

```js
var object={
  "data" :[
    {
      "question": "FirtName",
      "answer": "Daniel"
    },{
      "question": "LastNane",
      "answer": "Daniel2"
    },{
      "question": "Age",
      "answer": "80"
    }
  ]
};
var newObject={};

object.data.forEach(function(question){
  newObject[question.question]=question.answer;
  });
// {"FirtName" : "Daniel", "LastNane" : "Daniel2", "Age" : "80"}
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert to the object you desire - see demo below:

```js
var array = [{"question": "FirtName","answer": "Daniel"},{"question": "LastNane","answer": "Daniel2"}, {"question": "Age","answer": "80"}];

var result = array.reduce(function(p, c) {
  p[c.question] = c.answer;
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ['answer'] is better written in dot notation

Comment: @YosvelQuintero **both** representations are equivalent unless the key *is* a number :D

Answer (score 1):

This code will get you the output you require

```
var object = {
  "data": [{
    "question": "FirtName",
    "answer": "Daniel"
  }, {
    "question": "LastNane",
    "answer": "Daniel2"
  }, {
    "question": "Age",
    "answer": "80"
  }]
};

var result = '"data":' + JSON.stringify(object.data.reduce(function (result, item) {
  return result[item.question] = item.answer, result;
}, {})).replace('{', '[').replace('}', ']');
console.log(result);
// "data":["FirtName":"Daniel","LastNane":"Daniel2","Age":"80"]
```